# Banner hides the Search Bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Just spent a minute looking for the Search Function until I realized that the "Welcome to this site, here is the FAQ" banner is hiding the top banner and therefore the search box.

On StackOverflow, the banner pushes down the content, which isn't that esthetically pleasing but doesn't hide the search bar :)

Not sure that the solution is (Transparent? Realize it's a PEBKAC

Comment: I'm  looking into this.

Comment: Please not transparent... text over text with transparency is not pretty

Comment: This issue still exists today.

Comment: Not a PEBKAC in my opinion. This is an inconsistency that should be fixed. @Jin: What did you find out; could you please post back?

Comment: Is there a search bar too? I was about to ask - how to search threads here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So uh, yeah....we removed that damn banner, it was annoying.

Answer (score 3):

The banner pushing the content down works well on Webmasters too. It has the advantage of not hiding the login link either which requires to dimiss the banner first and slows things down.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst this is still the case, I'm not sure it's a bug (I seem to remember Jin mentioning at the time that he'd found out how to avoid pushing the content down by the banner). The banner does have its red X to close too.

If it were to change, perhaps it would be worth inserting the banner between the top line (the one with the white background on meta, black on the main site) and the middle grey containing all the links?